# Collapse subcategories in post edit screen

Tags: categories, admin, plugin-recommendation

Is there a plugin to collapse/expand subcategories in the post edit screen?

In other words, I'm looking for analog of [CMS Tree Page View](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/cms-tree-page-view/) plugin, but for categories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found it!

[Intuitive Category Checklist](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/intuitive-category-checklist/)